# Refreshing Angular RouteProvider route causes a 404 error with Python

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My url mapping works great using angular ng-route module, until I hit refresh. Then I get a 404 error. I am using plain html on python SimpleHTTPServer

directory Tree

```
.
└── test1
    ├── html
    └── static
        ├── css
        └── js
```

server is run inside test1 directory all html files inside html folder

routing is done inside app.js

```
var eclassApp = angular.module('eclassApp', 
    ['ngRoute', 'eclassControllers' ]
);

eclassApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/',{
                templateUrl: '/html/student-list.html',
                controller: 'StudentsListCtrl',
            }).
            when('/students/:studentId',{
                templateUrl: '/html/student-details.html',
                controller: 'StudentDetailsCtrl',

            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled:true
            });
    }]
);
```

I can navigate to my urls from within the app but when on a page and refresing I get a 404 error. Moving back (history) i get the same error. Why is that? Is it because I don't use the hash symbol?

Comment: with HTML5 mode, you have to have a server route which redirects to your app page corresponding to any (or all) routes that are to be handled by the client.  which server technology are you using?

Comment: I am using python -m SImpleHTTPServer for clearly testing and quick tutorial. Is this the problem? The server i am using?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 mode in Angular uses PushState, to silently change the URL without making a server request.  This does not work for new requests or refreshes.  The HTML being served from the Server is **always** `/index.html`. HTML PushState can't change the server page until it's actually loaded, but can't actually load from the requested url of `/students/1234` (as an example from your code).

In Python SimpleHTTPServer, you can add something along the lines of this code to force the server to load `/index.html`:

```
if not os.path.exists(request_file_path):
    self.path = 'index.html'
```

If you use the default routing mode instead, the behavior is quite different.  'Hash' routing uses the `#`, giving you routes like `/index.html/#/students/1234`.  The hash is interpreted by the browser as an anchor, and your server will **always** get the correct request for `/index.html`.

One thing to note, however, is that due to script load timings, the initial hash route may not be intercepted by the route provider, since the scripts have to load before they can interpret the hash string.  In hash routing mode, it's common for page refreshes to load your default state.

Comment: If i don't use html5 mode will it work with refresh?

Comment: BTW i am just using python -m SimpleHTTPServer and not a python module I created

Comment: then hash routing is probably your only choice in that scenario, since for pushstate support, you actually need to configure the server.